# How can I store log into a file via GridLogger?

Tags: java, log4j, gridgain

Currently I can print out logs in my console via GridLogger, but I am wondering how I can store logs into a file via GridLogger. In the GridGain conf directory, there are two files: gridgain-log4j.xml and java.util.logging.properties. How can I load these files in my application?

Thanks,
Bill

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GridGain always writes log to file by default (and additionally to console if verbose mode is enabled). If you haven't done any changes to configuration, log files will be stored in `$GRIDGAIN_HOME/work/log` folder. Note that when nodes are started using `ggstart.{sh|bat}` script, `$GRIDGAIN_HOME` will be automatically resolved to your GridGain distribution root directory if it's not set via system property or environment variable.

In case `$GRIDGAIN_HOME` is unknown (e.g., you're running a node in embedded mode inside Web container), log files will be stored in `$TMP_DIR/gridgain/work/log` folder, where `$TMP_DIR` is the temporary directory in your OS. Your can override this behavior via `GridConfiguration.setWorkDirectory()` configuration property. Work directory provided here will be used by different GridGain components including logger, which will create `log` subfolder for log files.

There is also an option to manually configure one of `GridLogger` implementations available out of the box, or even provide your own. `GridLogger` instance can be set via `GridConfiguration.setLogger()` property.

By default GridGain uses Java logger configured with `java.util.logging.properties` file included in distribution. If you want to switch to log4j, you will need to enable `gridgain-log4j` module - logger will be changed automatically and will be configured with `gridgain-log4j.xml`. For more information on how to enable/disable modules refer to `readme.txt` file located in `libs` folder of GridGain distribution.